# connection to database works on localhost but not online

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

My database works fine when it runs on my mac on localhost. But when I upload the code with filezilla online, the following warning occurs:

```
"Warning: mysqli::__construct() [mysqli.construct]: 
(HY000/1045):Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using 
password: YES) in /users/hassib/www/markme/index.php on line 248
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

The server I put the code on is hassib.bplaced.net. This is the code on line 248, which works fine on my mac on localhost.

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost','root','12345','markme');
if($db->connect_error):
  echo $db->connect_error;
endif;
```

Why does it work on my pc, but not when I upload it?

Comment: Does your live database have the user `'hassib'` with password as `12345`?

Comment: Do you have mysql installed on your server?

Comment: You realise that `localhost`, in the context of the server, is not the same `localhost` as your local server? (i.e. `localhost` is just the name for the server running on *this* machine)

Comment: @freeek yes mysql is installed.

Comment: @vivek_23 sorry 'hassib' was wrong. I edit it back to 'root'.

Comment: @CD001 this is my problem. I dont get the meaning of localhost. I think I heard that you only use localhost when you test your code on your own pc, just so that you dont alawys have to upload it. But when you upload it, you have to change it. I assume I must allow the server I uload the code on access the database. Is this right?

Comment: Ahh - there's *localhost* and then there's *localhost* ;) `http://localhost` (in your browser) would be your local development **web** server being accessed over HTTP **but** when you connect to a **database** server on *localhost* it just means the database server running *local* to your application. So, online that's a different database server to the one on your local development server... both are accessed at `localhost` but normally with different credentials. You're probably going to want some kind of local and online config files to hold the different username/password pairs.

Answer (score 0):

first create database on live(online) and create user with username & password and add user for this database then provide this username & Password to mysqli() function

Answer (score 0):

> "Warning: mysqli::__construct() [mysqli.construct]: 
>   (HY000/1045):Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using 
>   password: YES) in /users/hassib/www/markme/index.php on line 248
>   Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

From the error message above, it seems you are trying to connect with `root` user and not `hassib`

- Make sure the database is created on your server.

`CREATE DATABASE markme;`

- Make sure you have granted privileges to user `hassib` on your server.

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON markme.* TO 'hassib'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '12345';`

Comment: I mistakenly stated that, sorry. I have edited the post now. You may check again, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Are your sure that `localhost` is the correct host for your hosting provider? Some providers can provide another hosts for connection. Please, ask your provider for correct host.